# Replacing string by using regex and for loop value in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the value of first variable using second variable but i want to keep the commas. i used regex, but i don't know if its possible cause i'm still learning it. so here is my code.

```
import re
names = 'Mat,Rex,Jay'
nicknames = 'AgentMat LegendRex KillerJay'
split_nicknames = nicknames.split(' ')
for a in range(len(split_nicknames)):
    replace = re.sub('\\w+', split_nicknames[a], names)
print(replace)
```

my output is:

```
KillerJay,KillerJay,KillerJay
```

and i want a output like this:

```
AgentMat,LegendRex,KillerJay
```

Comment: What would be the problem with just replacing the spaces in the nicknames string with commas?  Also, I don't see what regex necessarily has to do with a solution here.

Comment: i have here complicated string that i want to replace. i want to keep all the punctuation

Comment: Your stated "input" is the output your current code is reporting.   Your output is essentially `'.'.join(nicknames)` -- I am not sure you are specifying the problem well enough to get the answers you need...

Comment: my bad. i forgot to replace it sorry. my output is "KillerJay,KillerJay,KillerJay". and i want a output like this: "AgentMat,LegendRex,KillerJay"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you are looking for should resemble something like this:

```
import re

testString = 'This is my complicated test string where Mat, Rex and Jay are all having a lark, but MatReyRex is not changed'
mapping = { 'Mat' : 'AgentMat',
            'Jay' : 'KillerJay',
            'Rex' : 'LegendRex'
}
reNames = re.compile(r'\b('+'|'.join(mapping)+r')\b')
res = reNames.sub(lambda m: mapping[m.group(0)], testString)
print(res)
```

Executing this results in the mapped result:

```
This is my complicated test string where AgentMat, LegendRex and KillerJay are all having a lark, but MatReyRex is not changed
```

Comment: You should put `\b` around the keys in the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar amended accordingly - correct, want \b(regex)\b to enforce whole word matches.

Answer (score 0):

We can build the mapping as follows :

```
import re
names = 'Mat,Rex,Jay'
nicknames = 'AgentMat LegendRex KillerJay'

my_dict = dict(zip(names.split(','), nicknames.split(' ')))

replace = re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda m:my_dict[m[0]], names)
print(replace)
```

Then use lambda to apply the mapping.